# Leaderboard activity on closing pause the game for few seconds

Tags: android, leaderboard

I did successfully done my leaderboard inside my game using the codes

```
public void openLeaderboardsActivity() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!mHelper.isSignedIn()) {
                    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                } else {
                    String leaderboardId = getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.leaderboard_id);
                    startActivityForResult(mHelper.getGamesClient()
                            .getLeaderboardIntent(leaderboardId), 1001);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void submitLeaderboardsScore() {
        if (mHelper != null && mHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            mHelper.getGamesClient().submitScore(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.leaderboard_id),
                    GamePreferences.getInstance().getHighscore());
        }
    }
```

But problem is that when i took the leaderboard from menu and came back the game is paused for like 4 sec and then it resumes, same happen when i take the in app purchase activity too.Can i know if i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved @mrfarts?  I have exactly the same issue......

Comment: nope its still there.

Comment: I'll let you know if I resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Is your app OpenGL?  If it is,  then when you start your leaderboard, your main activity's EGL Context is probably being thrown away (normal, but irritating Android behavior).  Then when you exit the leaderboard, the pause happens while the context is re-created and all of your texture etc are re-loaded (which typically happens in onSurfaceCreated).

So, you need to try to avoid the context being lost, and therefore, re-created everytime you pause your activity.

If you're targeting Honeycomb or above, then you could simply try adding this into your activity:

```
getPreserveEGLContextOnPause();
```

Otherwise you can try the following:

In your activity's onPause(), remove your **view.onPause()** to stop the context being trashed.  Instead, put this line:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then override **onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)** to bring focus back when your app is re-launched....

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && view.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
         view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }   
}
```

This should prevent the context being lost and therefore, those annoying pauses! :-)